# Uses of the Logistic Growth Model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

My question concerns the logistic differential equation $$y'=y(b-ay),$$

where  $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, and its solution $$y(t) = \frac{b}{a+ae^{-bt}},$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

> The logistic differential equation has well-documented uses in
> population models, but can anyone provide a list of other scenarios that we can model with this equation? The more examples, the better.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like this is a homework question.  Perhaps it will help to observe that this equation describes something growing (b*y) but competing with itself (-a*b*y^2) such that past a certain point (b/a) it cannot grow further due to competition with itself.  Given that, could you take a crack at answering the question and we can give you a sense of whether you're going the right direction?

Comment: Not homework (the new academic year in my country has not yet started!). I was just curious as I never seem to see this sort of ODE used in any other context.